# how to apply lambda functions to rows meeting a condition in PANDAS

Tags: pandas, lambda

I am trying to apply a function row-wise to a pandas dataframe with the following

```
df.loc[df.var1==123,'coltoChange']=df.apply(lambda row: myfunc(row.var1, row.var2),axis=1)
```

The idea is to apply the function only to rows where value of `var1` is `123`. But when I run this statement, it still tries to run every single row in the dataframe.

Comment: What is `myfunc` doing?

Comment: I ask because apply might be the wrong function to use here.

Comment: i had to simplify it. my dataframe has date ranges with millions of rows. so i run randomforestregressor predict based on row values and its date. take a long time to run, but i dont know how to 'vectorised' it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need filter in both sides:

```
mask = df.var1==123
df.loc[mask, 'coltoChange']=df[mask].apply(lambda row: myfunc(row.var1, row.var2),axis=1)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[123,123,3],
                   'var2':[3,4,5],
                   'var3':[1,2,3],
                   'coltoChange':[2,4,5]})

def myfunc(x,y):
    #sample function
    return x + y

mask = df.var1==123
df.loc[mask, 'coltoChange']=df[mask].apply(lambda row: myfunc(row.var1, row.var2),axis=1)
print (df)
   coltoChange  var1  var2  var3
0          126   123     3     1
1          127   123     4     2
2            5     3     5     3
```